# Web popup window from VB?

Tags: vb.net, popupwindow

I want to generate a web popup window when a user clicks a linklabel in my VB application.
Ideally the popup window will be using whatever the users default browser is.

Is this possible?

Any ideas how?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean? You want to open a site?

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start(Url)
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use `Process.Start("http://www.google.com")` on click event

Comment: Would there be anyway to specify the dimensions?

Like if i didnt want the page in question to be displayed in a full browser, I just want it popup style with no addressbar and no nav buttons etc?

Comment: I dont think so, why not use web browser control you can open up new form and load url there

Comment: I've been trying to use the webbrowsercontrol, but I'm having problems with the IE version not running the applet that is embedded on the page. basically it's for a support system to direct users to our livechat - I wanted it to open in a browser control, but while the webbrowsercontrol loads the page, the chat applet isnt loaded :( It throws an error about a "trim" function not being supported then dies

Comment: I also tried geckofx and webkit's firefox and chrome browser controls with no luck. this is literally plan D.

Comment: does that applet is important? if not use ScriptErrorSupressed  to true

Comment: I tried this - the error must be fatal, as the applet doesnt load at all.

Comment: Then I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.start) in the [LinkClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the LinkLabel

```
Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Process.Start("http://www.bbc.co.uk")
End Sub
```

If you want to specify the URL at some point earlier you could store this in the Tag field:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LinkLabel1.Tag = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
End Sub

Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
    Process.Start(LinkLabel1.Tag.ToString)
End Sub
```